# How to upgrade python from python3.7 to python3.8

Tags: python3

As python3.8 has been released, I wanna upgrade to python3.8.
By this, I mean I can run python3.8 by using command python3.

Comment: Wait a mere 11 weeks for Ubuntu 20.04. Any other change to Python3 on an older system will break your system quite horribly. Essential parts of your system depend upon the system-provided version of Python3, and must not be changed.

Comment: Okay, that's true though.

Comment: It is even less dangerous to install 20.04 NOW ;-) I have been running 20.04 since this weekend with both shell and budgie to test and it runs smoooooooooooth :) Not adviced on a production server but we mere desktop peepz can live a bit dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion 

Comment: FYI: As of today, Py3.8 is still in -proposed in 20.04.

Comment: One "related" question to @Rinzwind : Is python2 removed from 20.04 (beta)?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, there's a possibility. I searched read that they are working on removing python2 from 20.04